# How random_shuffle from vector in function?

Tags: c++

Here is my code;

This is my vector:

```
vector<string>day1{"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"};
```

I am using the vector in this code:

```
void Course::addCourse()
{
    string a;
    int b;
    int total;
    int courseAdd;
    cout<<"How many course you want to add?"<<endl;
    cin>>courseAdd;
    cout<<"Enter the name of course and number of hours.\nWARNING:For now just enter max 6 course hours"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<courseAdd;++i)
    {
        setCourseName(a);
        setHours(b);
        getCourseList().insert({a, b});
        total += getHours();
        getMatchMap().insert({make_pair(a,b),make_pair(day1[i],dayHours)});
    }
```

I want to shuffle the days before inserting the map.I mean here:

```
getMatchMap().insert({make_pair(a,b),make_pair(day1[i],dayHours)});
```

How can i random_shuffle the vector elements or where do i need to do this?

Comment: `std::random_shuffle` was deprecated in C++14 and *removed* in C++17. You *do not* want to use it. Use `std::shuffle`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle

Comment: What can I do for shuffle the vector? Btw my vector implemented in header file.

Comment: As I said above; use `std::shuffle`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before the loop, you could do:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 g(rd());
std::shuffle(day1.begin(), day1.end(), g);
```

To shuffle your vector.